# How to use postman to request an API that is protected with devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postman

I have a rails app using devise, in the beggining it was just using rails. Now i am adding some react using the gem react-rails.. To make the story short i have an API controller like this

```
class Api::CustomersController < ApplicationController
skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
before_action :authenticate_user!

def index
    customers = Customer.all
    render json: customers, status: :ok
end ....
```

and i want to access that info or test my API using POSTMAN.. Of course when i try the app just redirect me to the login page because of the "before_action :authenticate_user!".. Now the question is: Can i access to that API URL using postman? how?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Devise uses session based authentication. You can request an authenticated resource by first signing in and then passing the session cookie in your postman request. Of course this is not really practical for a real api where you want a token based auth instead.

Comment: so you don't recommend using this auth method if i am going to build an api service in this app?

Comment: No, I don't recommend session based auth for an API. Devise can do both but if you are just building an API I would use Knock which is a whole lot lighter.

Comment: I need both.. because i am now updating the webpage and i decided to use react.. but i can't stop the actual working webpage wich is using the normal devise for auth purposes.. So i will try to use both

Comment: also @max i already did what you said... i took the session cookie from the browser and used it in postman and it worked... so i think you are right... does not look very secure that way

Comment: Its not really security thats the issue - session based auth relies on cookies which means that your api will only be useable by browsers and not server to server for example. There are plenty of articles that discuss session vs token based auth and you should do some basic research here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't related to `devise` mainly.

You'll need to generate an `auth_token` for each `user` (and of course, create a db migration for it with uniqueness) and authenticate your user using `Authorization` header.

Otherwise, you can check the `devise` tokens solutions from here: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Simple-Token-Authentication-Example

Answer (score 0):

could you use any of these two gems are interesting to work with devise and a verification token

> devise_token_auth [documentation](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth)
>
> devise-jwt [documentation](https://github.com/waiting-for-dev/devise-jwt)

Answer (score 0):

Plain simple solution is to copy the browser session cookie (after logging in) into Postman/Insomnia/other client cookie.
Look for cookie value in browser dev tools, it needs to be copied into insomnia cookie value for the same page.