# Devise API sign_in doesn't work with postman

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, warden

I'm using Rails 6 in API mode and the latest version of devise.

I created rspec test for sign_in and sign_up and it works correctly they accept json answer and respond in json

When I try to test my API with postman it work for sign_up but not for sign_in.

With postman I got the following return

```
{
    "sucess": false,
    "message": "fail myapp_failure_app"
}
```

So I try to dig in the `devise gem` the problem and I finally found out the problem is here

```
def create
    self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
    ...
end
```

And in the `warden gem` the problem occured at the method `_run_callbacks(*args)`

```
def _run_callbacks(*args) #:nodoc:
  self.class._run_callbacks(*args)
end
```

Arguments passe to this method are:

```
[:after_set_user, #<User id: 4, nickname: "max", email: "test@test", birth_at: nil, created_at: "2020-01-12 22:44:19", updated_at: "2020-01-13 21:44:57">, Warden::Proxy:70223361236700 @config={:default_scope=>:user, :scope_defaults=>{}, :default_strategies=>{:user=>[:jwt, :rememberable, :database_authenticatable]}, :intercept_401=>false, :failure_app=>MyappFailureApp}, {:scope=>:user, :recall=>"sessions#new", :store=>true, :event=>:authentication}]
```

If I change the method to this

```
def _run_callbacks(*args) #:nodoc:
  return
  self.class._run_callbacks(*args)
end
```

It's working well.

I expected to find the solution by myself with digging in the gem and comparing my results with my spec but I honestly don't understand what this methods really do and why it's different with my spec.

Comment: Let put `i18n_message` into response to show error message of Devise. Maybe it's helpful

Comment: Maybe it can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58957941/how-to-use-postman-to-request-an-api-that-is-protected-with-devise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Devise` defines multiple hooks on `warden`, which are invoked via `_run_callbacks` method.
 It looks like you have a failure in one of those callback hooks. The hooks can be found here in the [Devise source](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/tree/master/lib/devise/hooks).
Also your `MyappFailureApp` isn't really displaying the error, would it be possible to define a nicer one ? Something like -

```
class MyappFailureApp < Devise::FailureApp
  def respond
    http_auth
  end

  def http_auth
    self.status = 401
    self.headers["WWW-Authenticate"] = %(Bearer realm=#{Devise.http_authentication_realm.inspect}) if http_auth_header?
    self.content_type = 'application/json'
    self.response_body = http_auth_body
  end

  def http_auth_body
    { error: [i18n_message] }.to_json
  end

  def request_format
    :json
  end
end
```

Comment: I feel shamed, by changing the error display I got a but error message "Please confirmed your email address before continuing". Thank you a lot !