# current_user is nil from react side , Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs

I have a `Rails` server which runs on port 3000, and a `react app` which runs on port 3001. The problem is:
when I want to create a new object from react side `current_user` is empty. I can create object from `Rails` side 
without any problem. I have checked the headers of request for both side, `"HTTP_COOKIE"` are set for both side. 
There is no error in console as well. I also put `skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token` in `application_controller`. The output of `pp request.headers.env.select{|k, _| k =~ /^HTTP_/}` when I am trying to create object from react side, is :

```
{"HTTP_VERSION"=>"HTTP/1.1",
"HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST"=>"localhost:3001",
"HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO"=>"http",
"HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PORT"=>"3001",
"HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"=>"127.0.0.1",
"HTTP_COOKIE"=>
"_ALL THE COOKIES ARE SET HERE ", 
"HTTP_CONNECTION"=>"close",
"HTTP_ORIGIN"=>"http://localhost:3000",
"HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH"=>"XMLHttpRequest",
"HTTP_X_CSRF_TOKEN"=>"undefined",
"HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING"=>"gzip, deflate",
"HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"=>"en-US,en;q=0.5",
"HTTP_ACCEPT"=>"*/*",
"HTTP_USER_AGENT"=>
"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:75.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/75.0",
"HTTP_HOST"=>"localhost:3000"}
```

Any idea what I am missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your rails session is different than the `react` session. You will need to implement `Authorization` header and fill your `current_user` on `before_action`.

Check my response here: [How to use postman to request an API that is protected with devise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58957941/how-to-use-postman-to-request-an-api-that-is-protected-with-devise/58958150#58958150)